# no url-change when using location directive

Tags: apache, location, url-rewriting

I have got my trac.fcgi under /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/trac.
It is protected with an .htaccess-file that has the lines

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /trac.fcgi/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^$ trac.fcgi [L]
```

My vhost.conf under /var/www/vhosts/trac.domain.com/conf has the following content:

```
<Location /trac.fcgi/login>
AuthType Basic
AuthName "trac"
AuthUserFile /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/trac/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Whenever I log in, then the URL is rewritten to http://trac.domain.com/trac.fcgi**/trac.domain.com**. (Why? How can I prevent that?)

Trac always answers with the error message

```
No handler matched request to /trac.domain.com
```

That is quite annoying.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the problem by adding

```
Redirect /trac.fcgi/trac.domain.com /trac.fcgi/wiki
```

to my .htaccess-file. The solution is ugly but it works.